# Can pylint check for a static comment / copyright notice at the top of all documents?

Tags: python, pylint

Can pylint be configured to check for a specific static text such as a copyright notice at the top of every file?

E.g. validate that the following two lines begin every file:

```
# Copyright Spacely Sprockets, 2018-2062
#
```

Comment: Using it from pycharm, which is just a terminal within pycharm. But it's not just for me, it would be for a team and everyone has their own editor/dev preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your own checker:

```
from pylint.checkers import BaseRawFileChecker

class CopyrightChecker(BaseRawFileChecker):
    """ Check the first line for copyright notice
    """

    name = 'custom_copy'
    msgs = {'W9902': ('Include copyright in file',
                      'file-no-copyright',
                      ('Your file has no copyright')),
            }
    options = ()

    def process_module(self, node):
        """process a module
        the module's content is accessible via node.stream() function
        """
        with node.stream() as stream:
            for (lineno, line) in enumerate(stream):
                if lineno == 1:
                    # Check for copyright notice
                    # if it fails add an error message
                    self.add_message('file-no-copyright',
                                     line=lineno)


    def register(linter):
        """required method to auto register this checker"""
        linter.register_checker(CopyrightChecker(linter))
```

See more about custom checkers [in the pylint documentation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/how_tos/custom_checkers.html). Also [this excellent post about the subject](http://atodorov.org/blog/2018/01/05/how-to-write-pylint-checker-plugins/).

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Diego in the comments for noticing that this was outdated, now we can just inherit from `BaseRawFileChecker`.

Comment: Very nice example. Thanks! One question though: Where do you place this file? Should it be imported in `.pylintrc` somehow? I don't see that in either of the referenced documents. Only references to adding this to the pylint project.

Comment: I think I found it. `load-plugins` in `.pylintrc`, documentation here: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/plugins.html

Comment: Function name should be `visit_module` instead of `process_module`